# Aligning multiple-lined equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm trying to align multiple-lined equations.

The equations that I want to show are in the picture below:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        f_{y1} &= f_{11} + \frac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
        f_{y2} &= f_{12} + \frac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
        f(x,y) &= f_{y1} + \frac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}(y-y_{1})\\\\
        x_{1} &= \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor & f_{11}\equiv f(x_{1},y_{1})\\
        x_{2} &= \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + 1 & f_{12}\equiv f(x_{1},y_{2})\\
        y_{1} &= \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor & f_{21}\equiv f(x_{2},y_{1})\\
        y_{2} &= \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor + 1 & f_{22}\equiv f(x_{2},y_{2})
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and the result of the code is following:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that `split` supports only one alignment point, and in your second block you want two alignment points, so your code throws an error due to that. `aligned` as in campa's answer supports more alignment points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me as you want to have two distinct "blocks": I would nest a `split` and an `aligned` (or two `aligned`) within a `gather*`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{split} % or aligned
f_{y1} &= f_{11} + \frac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
f_{y2} &= f_{12} + \frac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
f(x,y) &= f_{y1} + \frac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}(y-y_{1})
\end{split} % or aligned
\\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
x_{1} &= \lfloor x \rfloor & \qquad f_{11}&\equiv f(x_{1},y_{1})\\
x_{2} &= \lfloor x \rfloor + 1 & f_{12}&\equiv f(x_{1},y_{2})\\
y_{1} &= \lfloor y \rfloor & f_{21}&\equiv f(x_{2},y_{1})\\
y_{2} &= \lfloor y \rfloor + 1 & f_{22}&\equiv f(x_{2},y_{2})
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

There is no reason for `\left`/`\right` here. Even better (IMHO) I would use

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
```

and then use `\floor{x}`, `\floor{y}`. The starred form may be used if the delimiters are *really* to be scaled.

[image]

Comment: Why not `aligned` also in the first group?

Comment: No reason `:-)` for a single alignment point I tend to go automatically for `split`... Though I'm aware of the restriction about other material on the same line.

Comment: @campa But, I have to use \begin{equation} because of the numbering ... But if I use it outside of the gather*, it occurs an error..   

The error message is like this:

    Package amsmath Error: \begin{gather*} allowed only in paragraph mode. \begin{gather*}

Comment: @ShimHyunjeong you can use `aligned` instead of `split`, `aligned` instead of `gather*` and encapsule all of that into an `equation`. Rest is the same as above.

Comment: @ShimHyunjeong The picture you have shown had no equation number. You should be precise about what you are asking for `;-)` `gather*` gibes you unnumbered equations, `gather` numbered ones. To suppress the numbering in the first block you can use `\nonumber`. Lupino's solution is also viable but it really depends on _where_ you do want the number.

Comment: @campa actually, it depends on semactics. If the equation system is closed within itself, it belongs into an equation. Using align+\nonumber is just a bunch of equations where one is numbered, the other isn't. This may be over-the-top here, but if you intend to further process the tex source, say, into xml, a clean, contextual markup might become very important.

Comment: @campa and Lupino  Both of you, thanks a lot!!! I think I fixed it with your solutions. Btw, one more question! It is not in the center of the column right now (the whole euqations are.. ) How can I make it placing in the center of the column??

Answer (score 5):

Semantically, all these rows seem like different equations, one could assign separate numbers for them (for the last four I'm in doubt a bit), so I would just use two `align` environments (or if the spread between two aligned groups is too wide, one can use `alignat`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f_{y1} &= f_{11} + \frac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\\
  f_{y2} &= f_{12} + \frac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\\
  f(x,y) &= f_{y1} + \frac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_2-y_1}(y-y_1)
\end{align*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  x_1 &= \lfloor x \rfloor     &\qquad f_{11}&\equiv f(x_1,y_1)\\
  x_2 &= \lfloor x \rfloor + 1 & f_{12}&\equiv f(x_1,y_2)\\
  y_1 &= \lfloor y \rfloor     & f_{21}&\equiv f(x_2,y_1)\\
  y_2 &= \lfloor y \rfloor + 1 & f_{22}&\equiv f(x_2,y_2)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

There are starred versions, but it's easy to remove them and numbers will appear.

[image]

If though the last four rows are meant to be referred to as to one block (with one number) then I'd use a separate equation with `aligned` in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f_{y1} &= f_{11} + \frac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\\
  f_{y2} &= f_{12} + \frac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\\
  f(x,y) &= f_{y1} + \frac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_2-y_1}(y-y_1)
\end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  x_1 &= \lfloor x \rfloor     &\qquad f_{11}&\equiv f(x_1,y_1)\\
  x_2 &= \lfloor x \rfloor + 1 & f_{12}&\equiv f(x_1,y_2)\\
  y_1 &= \lfloor y \rfloor     & f_{21}&\equiv f(x_2,y_1)\\
  y_2 &= \lfloor y \rfloor + 1 & f_{22}&\equiv f(x_2,y_2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, try to express the semantics and not just put some characters together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `array` with `multirow`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{lr}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{f_{y1} = f_{11} + \dfrac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})}}  \\[4.5ex]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{f_{y2} = f_{12} + \dfrac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})}                   \\[3ex]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{f(x,y) = f_{y1} + \dfrac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}(y-y_{1})}                   \\[3ex]
x_{1} = \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor       &   f_{11}\equiv f(x_{1},y_{1})                        \\
x_{2} = \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + 1   &   f_{12}\equiv f(x_{1},y_{2})                        \\
y_{1} = \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor       &   f_{21}\equiv f(x_{2},y_{1})                        \\
y_{2} = \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor + 1   &   f_{22}\equiv f(x_{2},y_{2})   \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Still another solution, with `gathered`, `aligbed` and `alignedat`. In addition I simplified the typing of the floor function with `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}\lfloor\rfloor

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
\begin{aligned}
        f_{y1} &= f_{11} + \frac{f_{21}-f_{11}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
        f_{y2} &= f_{12} + \frac{f_{22}-f_{12}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}(x-x_{1})\\
        f(x,y) &= f_{y1} + \frac{f_{y2}-f_{y1}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}(y-y_{1})
\end{aligned}\\[3ex]
\begin{alignedat}{2}
        x_{1} &= \floor*{x} &\hspace{3em} f_{11} & \equiv f(x_{1},y_{1})\\
        x_{2} &= \floor*{x} + 1 & f_{12} & \equiv f(x_{1},y_{2})\\
        y_{1} &= \floor*{y} & f_{21} & \equiv f(x_{2},y_{1})\\
        y_{2} &= \floor*{y} + 1 & f_{22} & \equiv f(x_{2},y_{2})
\end{alignedat}
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]